# Unit of Work Pattern And Updating Entity Collection Properties

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, unit-of-work

I'm using generic repository pattern with unit of work implementation for my project.

Recently I've come to an issue which I could not solve. When I try to update an entity's collection property (i.e: Add a new associated entity) and call update on my UoW (to delegate it to repository and obviously EF) it does not save to the database.

My generic repository:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal MyDBContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(MyDBContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        internal virtual IQueryable<TEntity> BuildQuery(Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet.AsNoTracking();
            foreach (var include in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(include);
            }

            if (filter != null)
                query = query.Where(filter);

            if (orderBy != null)
                return orderBy(query);

            return query;
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = BuildQuery(filter, orderBy, includeProperties);
            return query.ToList();
        }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        context.Entry<TEntity>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

My Unit of Work implementation

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    //code removed for clarity

    public GenericRepository<CorporateServiceCategory> ServiceCategories
    {
        get
        {
            if(this.serviceCategoryRepository == null)
            {
                serviceCategoryRepository = new GenericRepository<CorporateServiceCategory>(context);
            }

            return serviceCategoryRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
       context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
using(var unit = new UnitOfwork())
{
    //unit.Companies is a generic repository instance for Company entities.
    var company = unit.Companies.Get(filter: f => f.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault();

    company.ServiceCategories.Add(new ServiceCategory {Name = "Demo"});
    unit.Companies.Update(company);

    //This is a call to context.SaveChanges();
    unit.Commit();
}
```

I expect this code to create a new Company -> ServiceCategory association and add a record to the database. When I do the same operation without Unit of Work but using DbContext itself, it works.

What am I doing wrong with my UoW & Generic Repository implementation?

Comment: Show your UnitOfwork.Commit() method body...

Comment: @st4hoo edited the post to show UnitOfWork.Commit() method body.

Comment: @Alaminut so I'm guessing the Company entity has a virtual collection of `ServiceCategories`, is the `Get` method lazy or eager loading the collection?

Comment: @SOfanatic, correct. Company entity has a virtual ICollection<ServiceCategory> property. Lazy loading and change tracking is enabled on context and Get method only encapsulates calls to DbSet<Entity>. You can see the implementation in the post. I've already shared GenericRepository class & the Get method there.

Comment: @Alaminut I think since you are lazy loading and inside the `Get` you are doing `AsNoTracking` it's probably not updating the collection automatically. Try eager loading the `ServiceCategories` and then working with that collection.

Comment: @SOfanatic, yes it worked. I'll add the answer in a minute, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to SOfanatic's comment, the problem has solved now.

I've updated my GenericRepository's BuildQuery method to reflect SOfanatic's suggestion and it worked.

Here is the updated BuildQuery method:

```
internal virtual IQueryable<TEntity> BuildQuery(Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.context.IsReadOnly ? dbSet.AsNoTracking() : dbSet;
            foreach (var include in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(include);
            }

            if (filter != null)
                query = query.Where(filter);

            if (orderBy != null)
                return orderBy(query);

            return query;
        }
```

DbContext.IsReadOnly is a custom property I added to my DbContext implementation. That way if I want to load entities in a kind of "read-only" mode (only selects) I disable lazy loading, proxy generation and change tracking so it increases EF performance a bit.